# Chrome is not correctly closed when KDE session ends

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde

I'm using Kubuntu 18.04. When I end my KDE session while having Chrome opened, next time I logg in the Chrome is not opened automatically (although other application active during loggout are opened). When I open it maually it only shows an error saying chrome not was ended properly asking whether I want to restore the session. I've found couple of answers but they are either not answered or the fix is not working for me (I have the "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed" unticked).

Comment: IIRC this is a chrome bug where it does not close properly when asked to by the OS (e.g. when terminating a session). You could try to write a script to manually close it when logging out.